# Android : MyRelativeLayout cannot get MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE/UP in the blank

Tags: android, touch-event

```
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
private int xx = 600;

...... //constructor

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.e("ev.getActionMove", ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ? "true" : "false");
    Log.e("ev.getActionDown", ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ? "true" : "false");
    Log.e("ev.getActionUp", ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ? "true" : "false");
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

I use this Layout as a root view in the MainActivity. And it contains 2 children. One of them is a RelativeLayout(child_1) which contains a Button, and another is a Button.

These codes are working when I touch on buttons but not in the blank, even in the blank of "child_1".
How can I solve this problem?
Thank you very much!